# Difference between passing values and reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was trying to understand difference between call by value and call by reference. Someone explained me that by reference changes actual memory location value, whereas the call by value just changes the instance(virtual value) but not actual one. So I tried to make that program check how by value and by reference work. My program is not working, Am i implementing logic correctly?

Here is the revised version of solved and working code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pro = new Program();
        int i = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Call By Value:  ");
        pro.byVal(i);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nCall By Reference:  ");
        pro.byRef(ref i);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void byVal(int i)            //*******   Call by Value    *******//
    {
        i = 2;
    }
    public void byRef(ref int i)        //*******   Call by Refrence    *******//    
    {
        i = 3;
    }
```

Comment: does this code really compile?

Comment: What do you mean by "My program is not working"? What do you want to achieve? Please refer to this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: Yes it does @MongZhu

Comment: I get a compiler error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'testproj.Program.byVal(int)' `

Comment: Create object of class file, then call the methods through that object. Here is the revised version:

Comment: Program pro = new Program();
pro.byVal(i);
pro.byRef(ref i); like this

Comment: @smnizamani it would be good to edit your post with this revised version. At this point your program is "not working" as it is not only because of the missing `ref`.

Comment: @MongZhu Done sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the call

```
byRef(i);
```

to

```
byRef(ref i);
```

if you want to call it by reference.